# Trigger colorbox when using a dropdown

Tags: jquery, overlay, colorbox, eventtrigger

I'm trying to get individual divs with profile information to overlay using colorbox when someone selects a name from a dropdown. So, if someone clicked on 'Name 1' which has a value of #p01 in my dropdown, then the div with the ID of #p01 would be displayed using colorbox.

However, I can't seem to get this to work. Can anyone see anything in my code that might be causing the problem?

Many thanks,

Osu

---

### HTML

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="chooseprofile">
    <select name="profiledd" id="profiledd">
        <option value="" selected="yes">- Please select -</option>
        <option value="#p01">Name 1</option>
        <option value="#p10">Name 2</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

Div overlays:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="p01" class="profile">
        <img src="#" />
        <div class="profdesc">
            ...content...
        </div> <!-- End div.profdesc -->
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End div#p01 -->

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="p10" class="profile">
        <img src="#" />
        <div class="profdesc">
            ...content...
        </div> <!-- End div.profdesc -->
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End div#p10 -->
...etc.
```

---

### JQUERY

```
$("#profiledd").change(function() { 
    var currentProfile = $(this).val(); // Grab select value and show correct overlay:
    $(currentProfile).colorbox({
        inline:true,
        current: '',
        innerWidth:"700px",
        innerHeight:"400px",
        transition:"fade"
    });
});
```

Comment: do you see any errors..?

Comment: @Sudhir I'm not seeing any errors in Firebug and also doing a little alert test shows that jquery is working...

Answer (score 0):

If a Jquery is popping up check that there is no Jquery conflict...

To test this do a simple jquery test like
alert($('body').html());

and see if it works.

and maybe try inline:'true' (with the quotes)

Comment: Just tried the test and it seems to be working fine i.e. no conflicts. It's strange, as the overlays are working when I use links like this: `<a href="#p20" id="p20-link" class="profile_link">Name</a>` and jQuery `$(".profile_link").colorbox();`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#profiledd").change(function() { 
    var currentProfile = $(this).val(); // Grab select value and show correct overlay:
     $(this).colorbox({
        inline:true,
        current: '',
        innerWidth:"700px",
        innerHeight:"400px",
        transition:"fade"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! This is the code that is needed - note the `$.colorbox({` part - you can read more under the Public Methods of the Colorbox project page here: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/.

Thanks for your contributions MMR and Sudhir:

```
$("#profiledd").change(function() { 
        var currentProfile = $(this).val(); // Grab select value and show overlay : 
        $.colorbox({
            inline:true,
            href:currentProfile,
            current: '',
            innerWidth:"700px",
            innerHeight:"400px",
            transition:"fade"
        });
    });
```